# Problema con selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, popup

Esto dice la consola, como que algo esta recibiendo el click que tengo predefinido

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (643, 119). Other element would receive the click: 
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)

[image: Necesito poder cerrar ese popup]

este es la funcion que lo cerraria, pero por alguna razon no puedo

```
def clearPopUp(self):
try:
  print("EL BOTON")

  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/button").click()
  print("Hice click")
except:
  print("NO ENCONTRE")
  pass
```

Comment: Puedes compartir el website para poder ver el código html ?

Comment: app.optiagro.com

Comment: `driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();")` te sirve esto?